# XDocument won't save to file

Tags: c#, xml

Trying to write some simple code and see if I can get a hang of this XML business.

```
public static void Save() {
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Repository/Test.xml");
    foreach (Produs p in produse) {
        // Yes there are multiple elements ('p'), have checked
        XElement root = new XElement("Produs");
        root.Add(new XElement("Name", p.getName()));
        root.Add(new XElement("Quantity", p.getQuant().ToString()));
        doc.Element("Produse").Add(root); // This "Produse" here should be the root element of the XML file, right ?
        //doc.Save("Repository/Test.xml");
    }
    doc.Save("Repository/Test.xml"); // moved here

}
```

No compile, or run time error, but nothing gets changed within the file. I do read from the file, so it does work.

Extra info on the .xml file (within visual studio):

Build action: Content
Copy to output directory: Copy always

Comment: You realize that you're overwriting the file on each iteration of the loop, right? I suspect you meant to put the `Save` call *after* the loop. But you should already see one new element each time `Save` is called...

Comment: But I do not. Ok, moved it outside, still nothing.

Comment: Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Are you able to see the document in the debugger after loading it?

Comment: The standard mistake is you looking at the wrong file.  Which happens when you don't specify the full path, like c:\foo\bar\baz.xml.  Real programs can never write to "Repository/Test.xml" and crash when Windows stops it from writing to a c:\program files subdirectory.  Use Environment.GetFolderPath().

Comment: Where is `produse` in your foreach loop defined? Also, use `doc.Root.Add()` to be sure your adding to the root element if that is your intention.